# How can I reset a Git repository to its newly-cloned state?

Tags: git, git-reset

Is there a git statement that has the same result as a fresh git clone?

So even if there are extra branches, extra files, other files, local tags anything... which command can accomplish this?

Comment: There's a git clone command....

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. What is the reason you want to do this? I ask because if you've gotten your repository into a bad state there's usually a better way to fix it than wiping everything out.

Comment: Ok removing the directory, looking vor the correct url...and then git clone works but  it would be convinient to do this without removing and recloning..

Comment: @schwern : sometimes some work was done, some things committed some not etc.. then dont't work on a project for weeks, other people keep working.. when you then come back to a project you want to start clean without figuring out where your local code is compared to the remote

Comment: @byenary Oh, there's much better ways to bring your repo up to date. `git pull` is the primary mechanism.

Comment: @Schwerm, I know but this can still leave me with a lot of unnecessary branches, tags and stuff which can be confusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your best option to remove all local artifacts is to make a fresh [clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

Otherwise, you have to run different commands to perform the individual components of the cleanup.

To get rid of all untracked files, use [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean), with any number of flags turned on to wipe out everything:

```
git clean -fd
```

Now reset all your branches to the remote version ([`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)) or delete them if they are local-only ([`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master

git branch -d local-branch
```

The same goes for tags. You can delete all local tags like this:

```
git tag -d $(git tag -l)
```

You can do a lot of these operations manually as well, by manipulating the contents of the `.git` folder, if you know what you are doing.

As you can see, `git clone` is by far the easier option.

Comment: Okay yeah I was afraid this was the case but maybe there was some secret single git command way :-) Ok so rm -Rfv  & git clone is the way :-)

Comment: this answer makes some assumptions ... the upstream you want to track is `origin` ( which granted is often true), and the default branch or the branch you care about is `master` ( less often true )

Comment: @Dan Those are examples, not assumptions. The assumption is that OP will use this code with understanding, instead of literally. I assumed that they (and future readers) read carefully enough to understand that `origin` is an example of `<name-of-my-upstream>`, and `master` is a sample stand-in for `<name-of-my-branch>`. I appreciate you making it explicit though.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to delete all local work I also think cloning the simplest thing. If the repository is big and/or the network is slow then you can use these options:

```
git clone --reference existing-clone --dissociate URL new-clone
```

Answer (score 2):

> *sometimes some work was done, some things committed some not etc.. then dont't work on a project for weeks, other people keep working.. when you then come back to a project you want to start clean without figuring out where your local code is compared to the remote*

If all you want is to bring your local branches up to date, you can solve this without wiping out your repository. Let's say your repository looks like this.

```
          D - F [feature]
         /
A - B - C [origin/master]
         \
          G - H [master]
```

You can get a very similar view with `git log --graph --decorate --all`, though it will be sideways.

You made some changes to both `master` and a new branch called `feature`. You already have clean versions of the remote work. `origin/master` tracks the remote work on the remote `master` branch.

This doesn't stay up to date automatically. You can update it, and all your other remote tracking branches, with `git fetch -p` (-p will prune any old remote branches).

```
git fetch -p

          D - F [feature]
         /
A - B - C - I - J - K [origin/master]
         \
          G - H [master]
```

Now that your `origin/master` is up to date you can look at it like any other branch to see the latest work.

You can bring any other local branch up to date with the latest changes with `git rebase origin/master`. This will replay any local changes on top of `origin/master`. For example, to update the `feature` branch...

```
git checkout feature
git rebase origin/master

                      D1 - F1 [feature]
                     /
A - B - C - I - J - K [origin/master]
         \
          G - H [master]
```

Or, if you're not interested in a branch anymore, you can delete it.

```
git branch -D feature

A - B - C - I - J - K [origin/master]
         \
          G - H [master]
```

Finally if you simply want to throw out your changes on `master` use `git reset --hard` to force `master` to move to `origin/master`.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master

                      D1 - F1 [feature]
                     /
A - B - C - I - J - K [origin/master]
                      [master]
```

And now you're up to date.

---

To answer the question about wiping out a repository...

Git repositories are generally very small (if they aren't that will cause other issues). Assuming you have decent network connection the simplest thing to assure a truly clean reset is to clone it again.

If that's not possible, the next best option is to [follow these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52998998/14660). But getting out of a jam by cloning a new repository is a bad habit to get into. Practice gardening your repository.

<strike>clone your existing clone and clear out its local branches and tags. This will guarantee things like `.git/hooks` and `.git/config` are reset.</strike>

First, clone the local dirty repository.

```
git clone /path/to/the/dirty/repo /path/to/the/new/new_repo
cd /path/to/the/new/new_repo
```

Then delete all your local branches and tags.

Git won't let you delete the current branch, so checkout `origin/master`, the upstream version of `master`.

```
git checkout origin/master
```

Get all your local branches and delete them.

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads
```

Get all your local tags and delete them.

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/tags | xargs git tag -d
```

Recreate a fresh local `master` from `origin/master` and check it out.

```
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

Set your origin to be the original repository. You can get that from `git remote -v` in the dirty repository.

```
git remote set-url origin <original origin url>
```

Finally do a `git pull` to get the latest version of the upstream repository, its branches, and update `master`.

```
git pull
```

As you can see, it's easier to garden an existing clone.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use clean. ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)) And maybe `git reset --hard` before if you want to reset changes.

```
git clean -dfx
```

- `-d` Also remove untracked directories.
- `-f` Force delete all files and directories without confirmation.
- `-x` Removes all untracked files, even ignored files.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure wheather this is really setting back everything, but at least for me it cleans everything and makes it ready for clean reusage, just like cloning it:

```
git reset --hard
git clean -dxf
git checkout master
git pull
git submodule update --init --recursive --force
```

**Caution: You loose all files not already in the repo ...**

- The "reset", takes back all obstacles to upgrade to latest changes (you want to clone fresh, so you WANT the latest changes).
- the "clean" removes all superflouus files, which are not tracked or elsewhere used
- the "checkout" sets you on the right path [but not at the topmost position]
- the "pull" has now free way to get all changes up to the top of the repo
- the "submodules", if any, are updated to the pinned versions.

I must say that the "submodule"-part is the most weak portion of git here.
In my personal script, I go (in addition to the commands above) into **every submodule path** and do a reset/clean/checkout/pull ...